# HOW to parse JSON data using gson library in android

Tags: android, gson

Response from URL

```
[{
  "name": "Bread Bakery & Dairy Product",
  "url": "/images/bread.jpg",
  "id": "5"
}, {
  "name": "Baby Care",
  "url": "/images/baby.jpg",
  "id": "2"
}, {
  "name": "Beverages",
  "url": "/beverages.jpg",
  "id": "6"
}, {
  "name": "Breakfast",
  "url": "/breakfast.jpg",
  "id": "1"
}, {
  "name": "Cleaning",
  "url": "/cleaning.jpg",
  "id": "3"
}, {
  "name": "Kitchen",
  "url": "/images/kitchen.jpg",
  "id": "7"
}, {
  "name": "Others",
  "url": "/images/others.jpg",
  "id": "9"
}, {
  "name": "Personal Care",
  "url": "/images/personal_care.jpg",
  "id": "8"
}, {
  "name": "Snacks",
  "url": "/images/snacks.jpg",
  "id": "4"

}]
```

SuperCategory.java

```
public class SuperCategory {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String url;

    public SuperCategory() {
    }

    public SuperCategory(int id, String name, String url) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

and this my logic for JSOn parsing using gson.

```
List<SuperCategory> superCategories = new ArrayList<>();
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson mGson = builder.create();
superCategories = Arrays.asList(mGson.fromJson(response.toString(), SuperCategory[].class));

But it is giving size 0 for superCategories.size().
```

Can someone help me what is wrong in parsing?

Comment: Try to use `superCategories = mGson.fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<List<SuperCategory>>() {}.getType());`

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried this. Still same. superCategories.size() is 0 only.

Comment: try this tutorial.............. http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

Comment: what gson version do you use?

Comment: I ran your code and was unable to reproduce your error.  `superCategories.size()` is `9`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changes your code from

`GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson mGson = builder.create();`

become like this

`Gson mGson = new Gson();`